# Remove duplicated line dividers with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have bootstrap pull down menu (MVC5 website) with dividers between some positions. Positions in the menu are displayed based on user permissions. Sometimes I end up with two or more dividers stacked up i.e.

```
<li class="divider"></li>
<li>@Html.RouteLink("option1", "Route1")</li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li>@Html.RouteLink("option", "Route2")</li>
```

Now I wanted to remove divider duplicates if they are appearing one after another. There may be a white space between 'li' elements i.e.

```
<li class="divider"></li>      <li class="divider"></li>
```

Hoping for help sending deep regards to all jQuery samurai's.
Mariusz

Comment: Maybe you want to fix the script that generates dup dividers instead ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to complicate your solution with jQuery, unless your HTML is more complex than your question implies, you can just use css to style a `.divider` element that immediately follows another `.divider` element.

```
.divider + .divider {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: Best is always simple. Kudos :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
$('.divider').each(function(){
    if($(this).next().hasClass("divider")){
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: You could, and yes this would/should work, but why would you?

Comment: Of course could, sorry :D Your solution is the better way of course, but he asked for a jquery solution, thats why i posted this. ;)

Comment: There's no need to apologise, I hadn't intended to sound do critical. And yes, aristo did ask for a jQuery solution.

Comment: I love both of them :-)